# Linux shell: How to give parameter to alias of find command?

Tags: linux, parameters, grep, find, alias

E.g, I wish to lookup current directory(exclude ./bin) for all files named "Makefile", as argument and grep "library", like below:

```
find . ! -path "./build" -name "*Makefile"|xargs grep library
```

I don't with to type all these each time, I just want to make an "alias" with 2 parameters, like:

```
myfind "*Makefile" "library"
```

myfind's find parameter is fo "find" command as "name"，the second parameter for "grep" command, also I wish the asterisk "*" can be passes as part of parameter, without being parsed.

How to write such an alias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use function:

```
myfind() { find . ! -path "./build" -name "$1"|xargs grep "$2"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with an alias. You could write a small script e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
find . ! -path "./build" -name "$1"|xargs grep $2
```

Save it as `myfind` somewhere on your path and make sure to remove the alias.

Comment: or a small function.

Comment: Why is that better? It's extra work to `source` the file containing the function.

Comment: place the function in your .bashrc, and there will be no +1 running bash overhead +1 reading file overhead when calling the function. That's the goal of functions.

Answer (score 1):

You used the tag linux, so I assume that you are using GNU grep. GNU grep  (at least `grep (GNU grep) 2.25`) supports the following options, which make your task very easy. Let me cite from `grep --help`:

```
 -r, --recursive           like --directories=recurse
 --include=FILE_PATTERN  search only files that match FILE_PATTERN
 --exclude=FILE_PATTERN  skip files and directories matching FILE_PATTERN
 --exclude-from=FILE   skip files matching any file pattern from FILE
 --exclude-dir=PATTERN  directories that match PATTERN will be skipped.
```

So your task can be accomplisehd by:

```
grep -r --include=Makefile --exclude-dir=build library
```

Of course you can create a shell script or function to further simplify that.

Comment: @Troskkvs Strange, I am using this with ubuntu 16.04. Did you get an error message or an empty result?